# Core services, Content Porter, Template Builder access after installing Access Management

Tags: core-service, sites-9.5, template-builder, content-porter, access-management

We installed Access Management, As per documentation Access Management in 9.5 supports Classic UI and Experience manager. Classic Core services, Content Porter, and Template Builder still use Windows Authentication.

In this case, If a user who has windows account earlier as "CORP\TM42111" once login through Microsoft authentication and User created with email id "prasanna@domain.com", now we provide access to an appropriate user group in Tridion.

Can I delete my user account  "CORP\TM42111" or should I keep the account in the system to access Classic Core services, Content Porter, and Template Builder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Tridion Sites 9.5 Access Management works with Classic Content Manager Explorer and Experience Manager. It does not work with the desktop clients, Template Builder and Content Porter, nor with Classic Core Service APIs. Such clients require another way of authentication (eg. Windows)

Answer to question: yes, keep that user.